# When sonar performs an analysis of a webapp is it just analysing java code?

Tags: java, sonarqube

When sonar performs an analysis of a webapp is it just analysing java code ?

On the dashboard the langauge specified is "java" so I assume the total lines of code and all metrics are just based on java code. The sonar tool is not including, .jsp , .css , .html files etc. It seems obvious that it does'nt include .css files but I'm just making sure.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was downvoted, but I nearly asked the same question a few minutes ago. I found this question to be good, so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Sonar analyses only 1 language at the same time. So if you haven't specified another language (via the "sonar.language" property), Sonar will only analyse the Java code of your application.